# How to make Slack bot dynamically reply at the same channel using node.js

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I want to make my slackbot app to answer at the channel that the user mentioned, without manually writing the channel name inside the code.

-example-
problem : I invited my bot into channel `#hello`, `#hi`.I mentioned my bot at Channel `#hello` writing `@mybot hi there`, but it only replies to channel `#hi` which I manually wrote down in my code.

I want my bot to automatically find which channel the message came from, and answer back at the same channel that user mentioned.
Not like the code I wrote `` bot.postMessageToChannel('everyone', `Chuck Norris: ${joke}`,params); ``

Here is the link of the module that I used and my code
https://github.com/mishk0/slack-bot-api

```
const SlackBot = require('slackbots');
const axios = require('axios');

const bot = new SlackBot({
    token : "",
    name : ""
});

// Start Handler
bot.on('start', () =>{
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':)'
    };

    bot.postMessageToChannel('everyone', 'Feeling tired??? Have some fun with @Joker!'
    , params);
});

// Error Handler
bot.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));

//Message Handler
bot.on('message', (data) => {
    if(data.type !== 'message'){
        return;
    }

    console.log(data);
    handleMessage(data.text);
});


// Responding to Data
function handleMessage(message){
    if(message.includes('chucknorris')){
        chuckJoke();
    }
    else if(message.includes(' yomama')){
        yoMamaJoke();
    }
    else if(message.includes(' random')){
        randomJoke();
    }
    else if(message.includes(' help')){
        runHelp();
    }
}


// Tell a Chuck Norris Joke
function chuckJoke(){
    axios.get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/')
    .then(res =>{
        const joke = res.data.value.joke;

        const params = {
            icon_emoji: ':laughing:'
        };

        bot.postMessageToChannel('everyone', `Chuck Norris: ${joke}`,params);
    });
}
```

Comment: Which method for interacting with Slack are you using? RTM, Events, Outgoing Webhooks? Please add that part to the code example in your question

Comment: Just added([https://github.com/mishk0/slack-bot-api](https://github.com/mishk0/slack-bot-api)). Thanks for the feedback:)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://api.slack.com/events/message) you will find on `message` it returns you the data object whith `channel id`

then 
you can use `postMessage()` from the api you have used

> postMessage(id, text, params) (return: promise) - posts a message to channel | group | user by ID,

```
bot.on('message', (data) => {

    bot.postMessage(data.channel, 'Feeling tired??? Have some fun with @Joker!'
    , params);
    console.log(data);
    handleMessage(data.text);
});
```

Comment: With few mistakes fixed such as putting params inside that code it's not working :(   It definitely brings the channel id to terminal using ```console.log()``` but it's not working inside app

Comment: Could you remove the check `if`

Comment: Oh I think I can get the hang of it. Thanks a lot it really gave me good hints:)

Comment: Not really. I think it's my problem because I saw the same code ```data.channel``` other people using it seems to work very well. Don't know why :(